# How can I eliminate undefined variables with register_globals turned on?

Tags: php

My website has register_globals turned on.  With register_globals turned on, the variable declaration could be anywhere in the site. I am trying to clean up my Notices in the php-error.log file but I am unsure what would be the best approach.

Here's a sample Notice

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: arc_dttm in E:\pm\www\main\ts_data.php
```

arc_dttm is defined in another php file.  Because of register_globals, the value is available in my ts_data.php file.

Here's the line of code in the ts_data.php file

```
if($j==3||$j==5||$j==6||$j==7||$arc_dttm||$tabPerm=='R')
  $readonly = 1;
```

**Should I simply add isset() to each section of code that causes an undefined variable notice?**  For example,

```
if($j==3||$j==5||$j==6||$j==7|| (isset($arc_dttm) && $arc_dttm ) ||$tabPerm=='R')
  $readonly = 1;
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Why don't you turn it off? You shouldn't rely on it, it's a deprecated "feature" from 5.4 ...

Comment: @onetrickpony it's completely removed in PHP 5.4, not just deprecated. Deprecation was as of 5.3.

Comment: `isset()` is the best way to do it for many reasons, but you can also set your error reporting a little lower: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3079211/2812842

Comment: This is a very old site and it would fail miserably if I turned off register_globals.

Comment: I thought of eliminating Notices scrowler in my php.ini.  Wouldn't the optimal approach (in my situation) to be eliminate the notice in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

No, your error_reporting set on development, So don't worry. When you set on productive, everything is OK.

Comment: He asked how to fix the notices, not hide them. This doesn't help him solve his development issues.

Comment: you can set error_report, but you don't get another error.So after code, you can clean up from debug mode.